# the Cardlist component is not getting called upon changing state

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react js and is having some problem in my code. I have a Cardlist component which is returning my contact list layout when i pass my contactlist into it. I added a searchbox to search for a particular contact. The list updated upon entering some text in search box (I logged it out in console and it is working finely). The render and return methods are also working well upon changing search text ( i.e they are getting called everytime after changing state, I logged them out) but the Cardlist component is not getting called again. It still shows the same old list. The console.log inside this cardlist component is also not logging anything which simply implies it is not called again.

Here is the main component (not whole code shown, only the necessary part) :

```
constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            friendslist: this.props.data.friendslist,
            searchfield:''
        }
    }

onSearchChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({ searchfield: event.target.value });
    }

render(){

        var filterfriendslist = this.state.friendslist.filter(friendslistitem => {
        return friendslistitem.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.searchfield.toLowerCase())
        });

        {console.log( filterfriendslist )}

    return(
<div>
<input id="name" onChange={this.onSearchChange} className="input-reset ba b--black-20 pa2 mv2 db w-100 bg-near-white" type="text" placeholder='Search' />

                <Scroll>
                    <div>
                        {console.log( filterfriendslist )}
                        <Cardlist friendlist={ filterfriendslist } loadChattingUser={ this.loadChattingUser } />
                    </div>
                </Scroll>
            </div>
);
    }
}

export default Contacts;
```

Here is the Carlist component :

```
import React from 'react';
import Card from './Card';

class Cardlist extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        console.log("Clicked");
    }

    cardComponent = this.props.friendlist.map((user, i) => {
        return <Card key={i} id={this.props.friendlist[i].id} name = {this.props.friendlist[i].name} imageURL={this.props.friendlist[i].imageurl} email={this.props.friendlist[i].email} msgDatabase={ this.props.friendlist[i].msgdata } loadChattingUser={ this.props.loadChattingUser } />
    })

render(){
    return (
        <div>
            {this.cardComponent}
        </div>  
    );
}
}

export default Cardlist;
```

Here is the card component :

```
import React from 'react';

class Card extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            name: this.props.name,
            imageURL: this.props.imageURL,
            email: this.props.email,
            msgDatabase: this.props.msgDatabase
        }
    }

    fillChat = () => {
        this.props.loadChattingUser(this.state);
    }

render(){
    return (
        <div className="dt w-100 bb b--black-05 pb2 mt2 pa2 bg-near-white pointer" onClick={ this.fillChat }>
          <div className="dtc w2 w3-ns v-mid">
            <img alt="Profile" src={this.props.imageURL} className="ba b--black-10 db br-100 w2 w3-ns h2 h3-ns"/>
          </div>
          <div className="dtc v-mid pl3">
            <h1 className="f6 f5-ns fw6 lh-title black mv0">{this.props.name}</h1>
            <h2 className="f6 fw4 mt0 mb0 black-60">{this.props.email}</h2>
          </div>
          <div className="dtc v-mid">
            <form className="w-100 tr">
              <button className="f6 button-reset bg-white ba b--black-10 dim pointer pv1 black-60" type="submit">+ Follow</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
        );
    }
}


export default Card;
```

I want the Cardlist layout to change according to input in the search but it remain same as the initial list

Comment: It would be very helpful if you put your code in codepen or codesandbox

Comment: @Mirodil ,Sorry, I'm not introduced to codepen. I have a github repo of that project. Will that work ?

Comment: @Mirodil, here it is https://codesandbox.io/s/chatter-v08lh. The main file is components/contact/contact.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue on your implementation of `Cardlist`. In your implementation `cardComponent` field is precomputed field. It supposed to be like this:

```
class Cardlist extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log("Clicked");
  }

  render() {
    const cardComponent = this.props.friendlist.map((user, i) => {
      return (
        <Card
          key={i}
          id={this.props.friendlist[i].id}
          name={this.props.friendlist[i].name}
          imageURL={this.props.friendlist[i].imageurl}
          email={this.props.friendlist[i].email}
          msgDatabase={this.props.friendlist[i].msgdata}
          loadChattingUser={this.props.loadChattingUser}
        />
      );
    });

    return <div>{cardComponent}</div>;
  }
}
```

Here is codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/chatter-zdljq